# Fancytree wont load correct in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-express, fancytree

I have added fancytree to an mvc 4 application and it works perfectly when i run it on localhost, but when i publish it to IIS i get the following error in the chrome console:
[image]

I make the following bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fancyTreeWin8").Include(
                  "~/Libs/Fancytree/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fancyTree").Include(
                      "~/Libs/Fancytree/jquery.fancytree-all-deps.min.js",
                      "~/Libs/Fancytree/modules/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js",
                      "~/Libs/Fancytree/modules/jquery.fancytree.edit.js"));
```

Here is my projects folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to access your .../skin-win8/icons.gif file path to see if it can be accessed.

And make sure your static content is installed.

[image]

Comment: I can see that Static content is selected: https://i.imgur.com/88F0z8Q.png. And i can access the icons.gif with the following URL: http://domain.dk/Libs/Fancytree/skin-win8/icons.gif but somehow the application thinks it is in the root: http://domain.dk/skin-win8/icons.gif when run on iis. On localhost there is no problems

Comment: Can you show me the project structure after your publish to iis?  and do you set virtual directories in iis?

Comment: Here is an image of the project structure after i have published https://i.imgur.com/nwzY5dg.png

Comment: Do you have url rewrite in iis to change your path? and you say you run the application on localhost, Is it running in visual studio?

Comment: I haven’t used url rewrite on iss. And yes when I say localhost I mean i run it in visual studio. But it’s like iis changes the bundle path to root. I don’t know if it can be because I created the “Libs” folder and used that instead of the “content” folder.